# Parsing math expressions, what is the classification for this method?

Tags: parsing, math, expression

I've written a lexer and parser for expressions like `3-5*6*8`, which is compiled to the following tokens:

- Number(3)
- Operator(-)
- Number(5)
- Operator(*)
- Number(6)
- Operator(*)
- Number(8)

The parser then takes an approach which I feel is a combination of recursive descent and precedence climbing in reverse. It works roughly like this:

```
parse(3-5*6*8)
add(parse(3), -parse(5*6*8))
add(3, -product(parse(5), parse(6), parse(8))
add(3, -product(5, 6, 8))
```

Like this, a token sequence is parsed from lowest precedence to highest recursively. It also handles functions through the parentheses handling system, but that is beyond the scope of this question.

**Can this method be classified as any of the known operator-precedence parser approaches or is this kind of a new *(strange)* thing?**

The one thing I can imagine preventing my method from being classified easily is the multiple operand system for operators like `sum` and `product`, but this is needed by my specific application to ease the implementation.

Comment: Could it be [Pratt parsing](http://journal.stuffwithstuff.com/2011/03/19/pratt-parsers-expression-parsing-made-easy/)?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds a little like Dijkstra's shunting algorithm [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm)